# Outer Joins to find records with no matching associated entries

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to find all `foo` records which do not have any `bar` records that match a given criteria.

```
create table foo (
  id integer
);

create table bar (
  foo_id integer,
  name varchar(255)
);

insert into foo (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
insert into bar (foo_id, name) values
 (1,"name1"),
 (2,"name1"),
 (3,"asd"),
 (4,"name2"),
 (5,"name2"),
 (3,"name1");
```

Based on this .. only record `6` matches the criteria since its not tagged with `name1` or `name2`.

```
select
  foo.*
from foo
  left outer join bar on (foo.id = bar.foo_id)
where
  bar.name not in ("name1","name2") or bar.name is null;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you mix 'foo' and 'bar' in the names of the tables and values, it's confusing. What is you desired output? I get ids 3 and 6 which is correct for your question. What is your statement 'Based on what' is based on?

Comment: updated the names to be less confusing

Comment: mainly trying to find all `foo` records which have no related `bar` records named `name1` nor `name2`

Comment: Your query is correct.

Comment: its not tho .. since it returns 3 and 6 in this example above .. and it should only return 6

Comment: You have 'asd' record, which satisfies query for the id 3.

Comment: it is meant to be an exclusive condition, only return a foo if its NOT tagged with any item on the list. If its tagged its disqualified.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18858/discussion-between-piotrb-and-mladen-uzelac).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick with `left join`, here is how it should be. The condition you want to exclude is placed on the `left join .. on` part and you keep the `where .. is null` check:

```
select
    foo.*
from 
    foo
  left outer join bar 
    on  foo.id = bar.foo_id
    and bar.name in ('name1', 'name2')
where 
    bar.name is null ;
```

It can also be done with `not exists`:

```
select
    foo.*
from 
    foo
where 
    not exists
      ( select *
        from bar 
        where foo.id = bar.foo_id
          and bar.name in ('name1', 'name2')
      ) ;
```

Comment: That works but I was hoping to avoid the subselect

Comment: Let me test the join variant ...

Comment: Thanks that works .. so the missing bit was adding the condition on the join .. ;)

Comment: Yes, correct. The condition you want to exclude has to be in the left join and the `is null` check in the `where`. The `not exists` form is more clear and easier to write and usually performs equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this query:

```
select
  foo.*, bar.*
from foo
  left outer join bar on (foo.id = bar.foo_id)
where
  bar.name not in (select name from bar) 
  or bar.name is null;
```

Comment: Nope .. specifically ("name1","name2") is a parameter for this .. I'm trying to `select foo.* from foo` .. but limited to records which are not tagged by a bar record matching the parameter list